# What is wrong with this incompatible type error?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I can't figure out why I get this error.

Here is the code:

```
public static int WriteBirdType() {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("fugler.txt"));
String         line = null;
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
stringBuilder.append( line );
stringBuilder.append( ls );
}

return stringBuilder.toString();
```

Here is the error:

```
test.java:78: error: incompatible types
return stringBuilder.toString();
                             ^
required: int
found:    String
1 error
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your method has a return type of `void`, ie. nothing. You can't return anything as it stands.

Comment: Was supposed to say `int`, edited it now, i get this error when its written `int` and not `void`.

Comment: If you're returning "String", then your signature should say "String" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return type must match the method signature.

If your return type is `int`, then you need to return and int, not a string. `toString()` returns a string. If you need to return a String, then change the method signature to String, not int.

Do this:

```
    //change return type to string
    public static String WriteBirdType() {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("fugler.txt"));
    String         line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
    stringBuilder.append( line );
    stringBuilder.append( ls );
    }

     return stringBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to return a `String` when you declared the method to return `int`.  Either return an `int`, or change the return type of the method to `String`.